# No implementation for models.UserDAO was bound. while locating models.UserDAO

Tags: java, spring-mvc, playframework

I am creating sample application using play.

I am getting these Exception while running:

```
1) No implementation for models.UserDAO was bound.
      while locating models.UserDAO
        for parameter 0 at services.impl.UserServiceImpl.<init>(UserServiceImpl.java:24)
      while locating services.UserService
        for parameter 0 at controllers.UserController.<init>(UserController.java:26)
      while locating controllers.UserController
        for parameter 4 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:44)
      while locating router.Routes
      while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
      while locating play.api.routing.Router
        for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
      while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
      while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
        for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
      at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
      while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
      while locating play.api.Application
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

And My classes are below,

**UserDAO.java**

```
@Named
@Singleton
public interface UserDAO extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("select userId,firstName from User where userId =:userId")
    public List<Object[]> getUserDetails(@Param("userId") Integer userId);
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
@Named
@Singleton
public class UserController extends Controller {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Inject
    public UserController(final UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public Result getUserDetails(Integer userId) {

        JsonNode output = Json.toJson(userService.getUserDetails(userId));
        return ok(output);
    }
}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
@Named
@Singleton
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserDAO userDAO;

    @Inject
    public UserServiceImpl(final UserDAO userDAO)
    {
        this.userDAO=userDAO;
    }

    public MainDTO getUserDetails(Integer userId)
    {
        List<Object[]> query=userDAO.getUserDetails(userId);
        List<UserDTO> list= new LinkedList<UserDTO>();
        UserDTO userDTO=new UserDTO();
        MainDTO mainDTO=new MainDTO();

        for(Object[] rows : query)
        {
            Integer Id = (Integer)rows[0];
            String name = (String)rows[1];

            userDTO.setNumber(Id);
            userDTO.setName(name);
            list.add(userDTO);
        }

        mainDTO.setData(list);

        return mainDTO;

    }
}
```

Please help me to find out what is the exact reason for the above issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where is your implementation of 'UserDAO'? You need to bind that with 'ImplementedBy' or in a guice module.

Comment: Thanks for your response rethab. Now I used annotation like @ImplementedBy(UserServiceImpl.class) But now it is getting another issue  services.impl.UserServiceImpl doesn't extend models.UserDAO.
  while locating models.UserDAO
    for parameter 0 at services.impl.UserServiceImpl.<init>(UserServiceImpl.java:24)
  while locating services.UserService as UserServiceImple does not extend DAO

Comment: What is the package of your `@Singleton` or `@Inject` annotation? It should be javax.inject.Singleton and javax.inject.Inject. But there are other like from Guice and since you want to use Spring they wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes @Kris. I am using avax.inject.Singleton only. But I did not find solution.

Comment: Hm, then looks all fine to me. Although I haven't used Spring and Play together so far. Have you tried the original Spring annotation with @Autowired?

Answer (score 0):

You should autowire it or inject it.

```
@Autowired
private final UserDAO userDAO;
```

And in `servlet-dispatcher.xml`

```
 <bean id="UserDAO " class="com.dao.UserDAOImpl"></bean>
```

And you can also use @Qualifier in constructor

```
@Autowired(required=false)
public UserController(@Qualifier("UserServiceImpl") final UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}
```

Comment: And am not using xml like servlet-dispatcher.xml. Using only annotations.

Comment: Then provide `ByName=com.pkg.UserDAOImpl` in @autowired

Comment: Thanks Alot for your Answer @Parth Trivedi. I tried all above ways. But I am getting same exception as above. Where is the problem am unable to find.

Comment: What version of info.cukes.cucumber-java are you using? Are you using cucumber.properties or cucumber-guice.properties to define injector source?